# print evens number and odds number from an array

Tags: c

Declare an array containing these number and print the evens numbers and odd numbers
Now I initialized an array that containing 11 integers.
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int nums[11] = {11,3,9,7,6,10,13,17,2,8,3}; // create an variables that store integers
int evens[11] = {0}; // initialized an array to store even numbers
int odds[11] = {0};  // initialized an array to store even numbers

int length = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]); // get the length of nums
int nums_index = 0;
int evens_index = 0;
int odds_index = 0;

for (nums_index; nums_index < length;nums_index++) {
    if (nums[nums_index] % 2 == 0) {
        evens[evens_index] = nums[nums_index];
        evens_index++;
    }
    else if(nums[nums_index] % 2 != 0) {
        odds[odds_index] = nums[nums_index];
        odds_index++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",evens[evens_index]);
    printf("%d\n",odds[odds_index]);
}

return 0;
}
```

The major question is whether the output has problems when I compile my code.
The output is ：0 11 0 3 0 9 0 7 6 0 10 0 0 13 0 17 2 0 8 0 0 3
Why it could happened?
Thank you all.

Comment: using `i` for the index into `evens` and `odds` is your first mistake. All three arrays need their own indexing which eventually determines the number of evens and odds respectively. After that regurgitating them in the scan loop is your second mistake. Both should be dumped *after* you've populated `evens` with just the even numbers, and `odds` with just the odd numbers, using two follow-up iteration loop *separate* from the scan loop. Look at your code and [explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: You had code that never incremented `evens_index` or `odds_index`.  Now you've edited it to code that never increments `nums_index`.

Comment: I would expect your current code to print nothing but zero.  Take your print statements out of the the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need separate indexing for each array, advancing the index for `evens` and `odds` only when nums[i] value is one of the two.

Otherwise you would get sort of a copy of `nums` with zeroes in place of those numbers of the opposite type (odd/even).

For instance:

```
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evens[j] = nums[i];
        j++;
    }
    else if(nums[i] % 2 != 0) {
        odds[k] = nums[i];
        k++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",evens[i]);
    printf("%d\n",odds[i]);
}
```

This will compose the arrays like:

11 3 9 7 13 17 3 0 0 0 0  --- for odds

6 10 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  --- for evens

The second problem is that you are printing inside the loop, firstly a value from `evens` and immediately after a value for `odds`.
So if you want to display them nice and separate, you can move both printf outside the first loop, then looping again on each result array for displaying it completely, before proceding to the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintNumbers(int*, int);

int main(void) {
    int nums[11] = {11,3,9,7,6,10,13,17,2,8,3}; // create an variables that store integers
    int evens[11] = {0}; // initialized an array to store even numbers
    int odds[11] = {0};  // initialized an array to store even numbers
    
    int length = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]); // get the length of nums
    int nums_index = 0;
    int evens_index = 0;
    int odds_index = 0;

    for (nums_index; nums_index < length; nums_index++)
    {
        if (nums[nums_index] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens[evens_index] = nums[nums_index];
            evens_index++;
        }
        else if(nums[nums_index] % 2 != 0)
        {
            odds[odds_index] = nums[nums_index];
            odds_index++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Original List: ");
    PrintNumbers(nums, length);
    printf("Even numbers: ");
    PrintNumbers(evens, length);
    printf("Odd numbers: ");
    PrintNumbers(odds, length);

    return 0;
}

void PrintNumbers(int* numbers, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", numbers[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Original List: 11, 3, 9, 7, 6, 10, 13, 17, 2, 8, 3,
Even numbers: 6, 10, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
Odd numbers: 11, 3, 9, 7, 13, 17, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```